# How to get specific key for manytomany and foreignkey

Tags: django, django-models

I have three models:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class ParamText(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()


class Param(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    value = models.IntegerField()
    texts = models.ManyToManyField(ParamText)
    section = models.ForeignField(Section)
```

This is simple example. Now I want to create class with concrete datas:

```
class ObjectTemplate(models.Model):
    params = models.ManyToManyField(Param)
```

but I want put this model concrete ParamText in specyfic Param. My ObjectTemplate should contain many params[Param] (unique would be great) with only one selected ParamText for each Param.

How to realize this?

Answer (score 0):

first of all to create a unique parmas[parm] use the OneToOneField instead of manytomany .

and to access a specific key : every object has an id so you can use that

let p be an Param's object

so to get the section id from the param you have to use

> > > p.section.id

this would return a long int containing the id (primarykey) of the object.

I think the following will solve your one parmatext for each parma problem

```
class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ParamText(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

class Param(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    value = models.IntegerField()
    texts = models.OneToOneField(ParamText)
    section = models.ForeignField(Section)
```

Comment: Oh no - Param model may be a many ParamText objects (ManyInMany). Only  ObjectTemplate restricts many Params to specific Param->ParamText.

Comment: write a custom template tag that does what you want